# How are Type-Errors handled in Haskell's Either Monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, either

I am currently having problems understanding the Either-Monad in Haskell.
Either is an instance of the Monad data type. Therefore I can use the Either within a Do block like this ...

```
type MyAccount = Integer

transaction :: Integer -> MyAccount -> Either String MyAccount
transaction value account | value + account < 0 = Left "Error: insufficient funds!" 
                          | otherwise = return $ account + value

Test1 :: Either String MyAccount
Test1 = do 
          account_state <- return 1000                       
          r1 <- transaction (-200) account_state             
          r2 <- transaction (-1000) r1                    
          return r2
```

This is a working piece of Code: *account_state, r1 and r2* are of type Integer. Therefore the function *transaction* works properly. However..

```
Test2 :: Either String MyAccount
Test2 = do 
          account_state <- return 1000
          r1 <- transaction (-2000) account_state
          r2 <- transaction (-1000) r1
          return r2
```

In Test2 I have change the transaction value from -200 to -2000. Therefore *r1* should be the String "Error: insufficient funds!". Since *transaction* does not work with Strings, there should be a type error. But there is not ...
What is Haskell doing here ?

transaction (-1000) ("Error: insufficient funds!") should not work.

Comment: I think you may have mistakenly posted the wrong snippet: your `Test2` looks almost identical to `Test1`, except `-200` is replaced by `-2000`. Also note that none of that should compile, because function names can't be capitalized. Finally, there is no such thing as "Monad data type": `Either` is an instance of the `Monad` _type class_.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Replacing `-200` by `-2000` is exactly the point: the first does not overdraw the account, the second does. The other parts of your comment stand, though.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `Either` cannot be a monad, as it has kind `Type -> Type -> Type`; `Either String` can be (and is), because it has kind `Type -> Type`.

Answer (score 9):

> ...but **r1** is a `String`

It's not. `r1` is `Integer`, and it's always an integer.

This is how the `Either` monad works:

```
r1 <- transaction (-2000) account_state
```

When you run this code, the right-hand side `transaction ...` is a monadic action, with the type `Either String Integer`. However, the monadic bind `<-` assigns the *result* of the monadic action, which is always `Integer`, to `r1`.

If the monadic action is actually `Left`, then it is not possible to assign a value to `r1`, and in fact it won't happen... the function will return immediately instead.

You can translate the code to code which does not use monads (or at least does not use the Monad type in Haskell):

```
test2 =
    let account_state = 1000
    in case transaction (-2000) account_state of
         Left err -> Left err # Returns immediately
         Right r1 -> transaction (-1000) r1
```

I hope that the behavior of the function is a bit more obvious when we strip away the monads.

#### Some Notes

It's weird to see,

```
x <- return y
```

You can replace it with,

```
let x = y
```

which is simpler and easier to understand.

It's also unnecessary to write:

```
x <- y
return x
```

Instead, just write:

```
y
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the joy of monads in Haskell!

First of all, a lightly edited version of your code.

```
type MyAccount = Integer

transaction :: Integer -> MyAccount -> Either String MyAccount
transaction value account | value + account < 0 = Left "Error: insufficient funds!" 
                          | otherwise = return $ account + value

Test1 :: Either String MyAccount
Test1 = do 
          let account_state = 1000                       
          r1 <- transaction (-200) account_state             
          transaction (-1000) r1

Test2 :: Either String MyAccount
Test2 = do 
          let account_state = 1000
          r1 <- transaction (-2000) account_state
          transaction (-1000) r1
```

`Either` is an 'error monad'. it works as follows:

Each action is evaluated.

If it yields a `Right` (conventionally non-error value), that value is unwrapped and the following action is evaluated.

If the final action yields a `Right`, this is returned from the `do` block as a `Right`.

If *any* action evaluates to a `Left` value, evaluation *does not* continue to the next action, but returns from the `do` block *immediately* with the `Left` value.

Therefore, in your case, `r1` will only receive a value, and subsequent actions which can read `r1` will only be evaluated, if the action that assigns to `r1` yields a `Right`. `r1` will always be an `Integer`.

Other error monads, such as `Maybe`, work similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you to **Dietrich Epp** and **Silver Rampart**. Both of your Answers are a perfect explanation for the Problem.
Here is just an addition

```
do 
      account_state <- return 1000
      r1 <- transaction (-2000) account_state
      r2 <- transaction (-1000) r1
      return r2
```

Can be rewritten to :

```
do 
    (return 1000) >>= (transaction (-2000)) >>= (transaction (-1000))
```

where (>>=) is defined as

```
instance Monad (Either e) where
    return = Right
    Right m >>= k = k m
    Left e  >>= _ = Left e
```

Therefore the `Left e  >>= _ = Left e` makes Haskell ignore everything connected with the (>>=) operator, if the first result is Left.

Comment: Haskell makes Sense ... but a takes a lot of Time ... for a beginner ..

Comment: Keep persevering with this attitude and soon this will be a second nature!